# Gitlab pipeline is always failing with error message

Tags: asp.net-core, yaml, gitlab-ci, asp.net-core-2.1, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm setting up the CI/CD for my .Net core project.

I have configured for the only build stage which is failing with below error message:

> "MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The
>   current working directory does not contain a project or solution
>   file."

My solution structure is different. Project `.SLN` file is inside another folder its not available working directory.

My `.SLN` file is in Solution folder.

My solution structure image path:

[image]

Here my `gitlab-ci.yml` code looks like:

```
stages:
  - build
before_script:
  - 'dotnet restore'
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - dotnet build Solution/MyApp360.sln
  only:
    refs:
      - master
      - release
      - develop
```

What I am missing here?

Am I passing the SLN file path wrongly?

How to pass the `.SLN` path to the build command.
Any example is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running your jobs on Windows in cmd executor, then you need to write your paths with '\' instead of '/'. The line would then be:

```
dotnet build Solution\MyApp360.sln
```

Comment: I think that you need to add the same path to the dotnet restore command as well:

    dotnet restore Solution\MyApp360.sln